# java code templates eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, code-templates

I've got 3 files for eclipse code templates:

2 `xml` files, which have templates related to company information and author name, which are used when you create a java file

1 `.epf` file - eclipse preference file

I'm trying to use these templates by going to `windows->preferences->java->editor->templates->import`

But this is not helping. How do I apply these template files- xml and epf both?

Help appreciated.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here i am assuming that you are trying to import java templates

- If xml file begins with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><templates>`
  then it is for 'Code Templates'
  Location: Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates
- If xml file begins with

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
> <profiles version="12">
> <profile kind="CodeFormatterProfile"
> ```

then these are for Formatter

Location: Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter

- If xml file begins with

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
> <profiles version="2">
> <profile kind="CleanUpProfile"
> ```

Location: Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Clean Up

- For .epf files, select File -> Import -> General -> Preferences (now select file) and follow the steps.

Comment: Thanks MJSG :) how do I upload eclipse preference file?